# Java Server Help, method stops at ServerSocket.accept();

Tags: java

Can someone please help me with the following code? The methods runs until `ss.accept();` I run the `server.run` method drom a mainframe and it looks great up until that line of code. I tried debugging and once i get there it simply stops, no exceptions thrown

```
public class Server extends Thread{

    ServerSocket ss;
    private boolean running = true;
    private LinkedList<Participant> participants = new LinkedList<Participant>();
    final int SERVER_PORT = 4567;

   public Server(){

    try{ 
       this.ss = new ServerSocket(SERVER_PORT);

    }catch(Exception e){
       System.out.println("problem at...");
    }

    }//Constructor

    public void run(){

     try{




    while(running){

     System.out.println("35");


    Socket sock = this.ss.accept();  
     System.out.println("39");  
    Participant part = null;  

    part = new Participant(this,sock);  

    participants.add(part);  

    part.start();

    }


    }catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

    }//Server
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's waiting for a request from a client. Did you send a request from a client and try ?